# exponential function in R

Tags: r, model, exponential

I have basic knowledge in R, I would like to know how to write a code of an exponential function in R

```
F(X)=B(1-e^-AX)
```

where A=lambda parameter, B is a parameter represents the Y data, X represents the X data below.

I need the exponential model to generate the curve to fit the data; for example:

```
X <- c(22, 44, 69, 94, 119, 145, 172, 199, 227, 255)
```

PS: this x-axis in numbers (in millions).

```
Y <- c(1, 7, 8, 12, 12, 14, 14, 18, 19, 22)
```

This y-axis

any idea of how to write the code and fit this model in the data...?

Comment: Apparently, you want to do non-linear regression?

Comment: yes...as you can see the function

Comment: Look for a tutorial then. There are numerous tutorials showing how to do nonlinear regression in R.

Answer (score 2):

In **R** you can write an exponential function with `exp()`, in your case:

```
F <- Y*(1-exp(-A*X))
```

Comment: I got error once I run this: Error in exp(-A * X) : argument "x1" is missing, with no default

Comment: I edited your code (perhaps not visible until you read this comment) and because you didn't use **R** syntax. With your now defined `X <- c(22, 44, 69, 94, 119, 145, 172, 199, 227, 255)` and `Y <- c(1, 7, 8, 12, 12, 14, 14, 18, 19, 22)` vectors this will work (A has to be a parameter, e.g. `A <- 1`).

Comment: @J_F I'm not sure your edits are appropriate given this guidance: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code, instead I would address the incorrect syntax in your answer.